# Android ListView Response

Tags: android, listview

I have created a listview using arrayAdapter. It contains

1. A TextView
2. Two radio Button (i.e a radio group)
3. A EditText

Also, Added footer having submit button. TextView is setting dynamically.Radiobuttons have yes and no value.

Problem is , on clicking submit button , I want get all the values from listview send it somewhere, but *getting null values* for radiobutton and edittext.

Here Is My Code

```
    final Question weather_data[] = new Question[]
            {
            new Question(str[0], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
            new Question(str[01], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
            new Question(str[02], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
            new Question(str[03], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
            new Question(str[04], r1, r2, etext, radio_group),
            };

    QuestionAdapter adapter = new QuestionAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);


    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.securityListView);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);
    View footer = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_footer_row, null);
    listView1.addFooterView(footer);
    Button btnSubmit=(Button)(footer.findViewById(R.id.submit));
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    Question w1=    (Question) listView1.getItemAtPosition(2);

    System.out.println(w1);
    System.out.println(listView1.getParent().toString());
    System.out.println("Child Count is "+listView1.getChildCount());


    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Footer Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("In Footer OnClick");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Footer Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            myQue=(Question) listView1.getItemAtPosition(3);
            System.out.println(((Question) listView1.getItemAtPosition(3)).editResponse.getText()+" In Edit Text");
            System.out.println(((Question) listView1.getItemAtPosition(3)).radioYes.isChecked());
            // I want these 2 lines to print the answer (values entered by user). But showing null or values set by me at runtime.

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: You need to post your code

Answer (score 0):

so, there are several ways of solving the problem.

Try to get items from listView and them find the text and boolean values:

```
        public void footerButtonClick(){
            for(int i=0;i<listView.getChildCount;i++){
                String text=((EditText)listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id)).
                getText().toString();
               //and the same with your radioGroups.

            }

        }
```

or you can try to create static arrays of boolean and string values in your MainActivity class and to notify textWatchers for EditTexts and valueChangers for radioGroups. and when the text or boolean values are changing change them in static arrays. Then you can use this arrays when you'll push the button

Comment: don't understand what do you meen by saing set by user, and by you dynamically

Comment: Yes. Getting text by that way..but not working for Radio Button.can you give code for radioButton. 
The other problem is my listView.getChildCount() method returns 5. but in for loop i=3 and i=4 throws null pointer exeption..
Also When I type something in editText at position 1, then same text get copied in last editText of list view. I cant access the edittext at position 0 and 1. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to save all this info with some parallel data structure and when these value changes like when radio button change and text view text changes you have to update your values,send these values when click on submit button.